# ERROR: Trying to select an annotation which has not been added

Tags: ios8, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:firstAnnotation animated:YES];
```

After debug this line print below

> ERROR: Trying to select an annotation which has not been added

Also **viewForAnnotation** is not called .

What is the problem ?

any solution ?

Thanks in advance.